# Can I run postcss plugins directly against a postcss Result object?

Tags: postcss

According to [the postcss docs](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blob/master/docs/api.md#processorprocesscss-opts), I should be able to execute plugins against a postcss `Result` object the same way I execute them against a string of CSS (using `Processor.process`).

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I've demonstrated this "bug" [here](http://requirebin.com/?gist=c9a114e5a26a364580f454609be18802) (I also copied the code below for convenience). Just click on that link, open your browser's console, and click "Run Code" to execute the tests.

My question is: since this doesn't work, how can I run a postcss plugin directly against a postcss `Result` object?

---

### test code demonstrating the issue

First, I require postcss, a plugin, and a test harness

```
var postcss = require('postcss')
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext')
var test = require('tape')
```

Next I define some input css and the output I expect from running the plugin

```
var input = 'body { color: rebeccapurple; }'
var expected = 'body { color: rgb(102, 51, 153); }'
```

And now, the tests themselves:

1: Normal usage, proving the plugin works as expected

```
test('cssnext', function (t) {
  t.plan(1)
  postcss([cssnext]).process(input).then(function (result) {
    t.equals(result.css, expected, 'produces the expected result')
  })
})
```

This test passes:

```
ok 1 produces the expected result
```

2: Use the method defined in the docs to apply a plugin directly on a `Result` object

```
test('running plugins against a Result object (1)', function (t) {
  t.plan(1)
  // first run without plugins to get a Result object
  postcss([]).process(input).then(function (result) {
    postcss([cssnext]).process(result)
      .then(function () {
        t.equals(result.css, expected, 'produces the same result')
      })
  })
})
```

This test fails:

```
not ok 2 produces the same result
   ---
     operator: equal
     expected: |-
       'body { color: rgb(102, 51, 153); }'
     actual: |-
       'body { color: rebeccapurple; }'
   ...
```

3: Another attempt, manually executing the plugin function

```
test('running plugins against a Result object (2)', function (t) {
  t.plan(1)
  // first run without plugins to get a Result object
  postcss([]).process(input).then(function (result) {
    Promise.resolve(cssnext(result.root, result))
      .then(function () {
        t.equals(result.css, expected, 'produces the same result')
      })
  })
})
```

This test also fails:

```
not ok 3 produces the same result
   ---
     operator: equal
     expected: |-
       'body { color: rgb(102, 51, 153); }'
     actual: |-
       'body { color: rebeccapurple; }'
   ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue in test 2 — you forget to get second `result` argument in second `process` call. Correct test:

```
test('running plugins against a Result object (1)', function (t) {
  t.plan(1)
  // first run without plugins to get a Result object
  postcss([]).process(input).then(function (result) {
    postcss([cssnext]).process(result)
      .then(function (result2) {
        t.equals(result2.css, expected, 'produces the same result')
      })
  })
})
```

Issue in test 3 problem is that `result.css` is not a magic thing. If you will change `result.root` it will not update `result.css`. Here is a possible solution:

```
result.css = result.root.toString()
```